# Differential geometry book Ddo Carmo or Barret O neiL

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

Pros and Cons of these 2 books which to choose for a course in Differential Geometry.[https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Geometry-Curves-Surfaces-Manfredo/dp/0132125897](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132125897). or [https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Geometry-Revised-Second/dp/0120887355](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120887355).

Comment: You cannot become an expert by reading one book.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus  I do not have time in this semester to study more than 2 books for each subject.It is a matter of time.

Comment: My opinion is that do carmo is one of the best. Maybe make it your primary, and then have some back up books.

Answer (score 1):

From Manfredo I can say that he is a world reference in Differential Geometry and proudly that he is from the city where I study, Maceió-Brasil. His cons is that a very large and dense book for an introductory course.

Comment: If you understand a bit of Portuguese there are some video ailas by Professor Fernando Codá, proudly also created here in Maceió.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCmhtirgxmI